# C# SHA256 on files with very long file paths

Tags: c#, windows, filepath, sha256

I get a `List<string>` of files via recursion through `FileFinderEx` via win32 api (DllImport of kernel32). (There's several questions that go over how this is done).

I handle fully qualified paths greater than `MAX_PATH` by using `\\?\UNC\` and `\\?\`.

Also, from win32 api I can grab the "short path" (8.3 name) of file via `GetShortPathNameW`.

Now that I have the `List<string>` of fully qualified paths to files, I want to iterate over each path and place their `SHA256` into another list (same index).  So roughly, something like this:

```
List<string> files = new List<string>();
//win api function populates files ...
List<string> hash = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
{
    using (var stream = new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(files[i]), 1200000))
    {
        SHA256Managed sha = new SHA256Managed();
        byte[] checksum = sha.ComputeHash(stream);
        hash.Add(BitConverter.ToString(checksum).Replace("-", String.Empty));
        stream.Close();
    }
}
```

The problem I face is even if I give it the "short path" (8.3 name) the `File.OpenRead` always throws exception if the fully qualified UNC name is greater than `MAX_PATH` (260 I believe).

So... now what?  Is there some win32 api function I can import to do the reading instead of `File.OpenRead`?  Or is there some other .NET method to open files with long file paths?  Any tips to get around this limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in kernel32.dll. Despite it's name, you can use it to either read or create a file, and the Unicode version will allow you to use paths longer than `MAX_PATH`.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
    string lpFileName,
    EFileAccess dwDesiredAccess,
    EFileShare dwShareMode,
    IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
    ECreationDisposition dwCreationDisposition,
    EFileAttributes dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    IntPtr hTemplateFile);
```

There is a good series of posts (part 1 [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton.aspx)) on the BCL Team's blog from a few years back covering the topic of long paths in Windows and .NET, which I think you'd find useful.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't sought this one before due to its misleading name!